# Find out from which phrase a tweet is coming from

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have following stream and when I receive a tweet, I would like to find from which of the following phrase and users, I have received the tweet.

```
stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'],follow=['#foo','#bar'])
```

Is there any support on twitter api or tweepy. If not what is the best manual way of it?

[Here](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics) is an example  and when a tweet has received, I would like to know if this is coming because of python phrase or javascript or ruby or even a combination of all of them

Comment: Will it be somehow inobvious?!

Comment: no, it's not, because I production I will have 100-500 phrases in one stream + I will have 50 streams, so when a stream is coming I won't have any idea where it is come from

Comment: But my point is the tweets will contain whatever you searched for, because that's how you got them, so just check against what you're searching for. What are you actually trying to achieve? If you need to be more precise, why not have more streams with fewer phrases?

Comment: I actually can't change the number of phrases and streams as there are other systems that are using them.  I think one way would be to compare the received tweet with the all phrases in the track but it won't work for follow

Comment: Could you please give some actual examples of what you're doing? A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: here is one good example http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/ and when a tweet has received, I would like to know if this is coming because of python word or javascript or ruby or even a combination of all of them.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to give a usable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the confusion lies with actually understanding the Streaming API.

Once you open a connection with your requirements such as `stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'],follow=['#foo','#bar'])`, Twitter will send you all the tweets (within their specified limit) that match that criteria. They do *not* do any type of separation, you receive everything at once.

What you can do is filter (tokenize) each tweet for the those words, this can be done after you collect the number of tweets you want, or through some type of streaming, real-time, method.

From the example you provided, he did a post-processing of tweets and plotted the frequency of mentions from all the data he received during the collection period.

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: thanks, I wondered if there is a native way and avoid manual/post processing but it seems there are no way to do it.